# After reboot, nothing shows up: Ubuntu installation

Tags: wubi

After passing through all the steps mentioned [*here*](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows).

I see nothing but a black screen, even after I wait for more than 15 minutes, nothing shows up. Help plz.

Comment: absolutely nothing showed up

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing ctrl-alt-4 on your keyboard. Then manually login, load lightdm by typing "lightdm". If all else fails delete the Ubuntu partition and re-install, or you could check what graphics card you have and try to install the driver.